# SQL Server trigger Inserted and Deleted to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, triggers

I need to create a SQL Server trigger. I want to save the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` records to an audit table.

My audit table is;

```
  ID,
  INSERTED_XML,
  DELETED XML,
  CHANGETIME
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made even an attempt? If so, please edit your question and add it.

Comment: So what have you tried? This isn't the do your job for you service you know. And you need to specify the database backend, triggers are differnt on every database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple audit trigger - as per the comments, posting your effort thus far is a requisite of the StackOverflow community.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_MyTable ON dbo.MyTable FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
   AS
      BEGIN
         SET NOCOUNT ON;
         INSERT INTO AuditTable(ID, INSERTED_XML, CHANGETIME)
            SELECT ID, SomeXmlColumn, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM INSERTED;

         INSERT INTO AuditTable(ID, DELETED_XML, CHANGETIME)
            SELECT ID, SomeXmlColumn, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            FROM DELETED;
      END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2eec/2)